# How to count number in a string using .match in JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

could you please help me to solve this problem using .match regex? I dont know how to count numbers in this string. After I use match, I get an array and I cant plus those numbers together.

```
function func() {
  let count = 0;
  const text = "hi 3 how 10 are you 44"
  const regex = /\d+/g; 
  const matches = text.match(regex); 

  if (count === 57) {
    return 'yes';
  }
}
func();
```

Comment: So you need to loop over the matches

Comment: for(var i=0; i< matches.length; i++) console.log(matches[i])

Comment: Basic math.....

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Array method `reduce` is what you're looking for.

Here's a modified version of your function that will return the sum of numbers matches by your regex.

```js
function func() {
  let count = 0;
  const text = "hi 3 how 10 are you 44"
  const regex = /\d+/g;
  const matches = text.match(regex);

  if (!matches) return count; // no matches, return zero

  count = matches.reduce( // iterate over matches Array, passing through reduce function
    (acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), // reduce values, sum matched numbers
    0 // initial value
  )

  return count
}

const someCondition = func();

if (someCondition === 57) {
  console.log('yes')
}
```

My next suggestion would be to pass `text` as a argument to the function `func` followed by renaming the function to something better, such as `sumNumbersInString`.

Comment: No need for `+=`. Just `+` since the returned value will be the value of `acc` in the next iteration.

Comment: Ian thanks for your help. Is there any chance to use the same method that you used but with my let count = 0; variable? I want to push the result of count matches to this variable

Comment: @Node.jsMaster, yes, the value of `count` will be the sum of numbers before the `return` as it is reassigned the value of the reduce

Comment: @Node.jsMaster swap the return for your `if` statement and you'll have your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Regex match returns an array, so just grab the length.

```js
function func() {
    let string = 'hi 3 how 10 are you 44';
    let count = (string.match(/\d+/g) || []).length;
    console.log(count);
    return count;
}
func()
```

Comment: it shows only one number, I have to plus all those numbers in the string plus I have to use if statement that you skipped.

Comment: I see. I'll fix my answer quickly.

Comment: Nevermind, someone else solved it

Comment: can you please sum the numbers in the string and add them to let count = 0; variable that I have in my code? I dont know how to do that. Basically with for loop I think it could be possible